# Ways to visualize parallel processing

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, visualization, distributed, distributed-computing

Are there some common ways to visualize parallel algorithms/distributed processes. Same as state machines or UML sequence diagrams are used for single threaded execution?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Vertical line is line of life of object. It can be separate thread or all objects can live on single thread. You may show multiple threads on Sequence diagram but it is bit crude. I am searching for some alternative ways.

Comment: What about paths? http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2012/11/02/us/politics/paths-to-the-white-house.html

Comment: @MarcoCI It is concept similiar to UML communication diagram http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/communicationDiagram.htm

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [UML timing Diagram](http://www.sparxsystems.com/resources/uml2_tutorial/uml2_timingdiagram.html), it might suit your needs.

In general it is hard to draw a generic timing diagram but drawing specific scenario's can be done using Timing, Activity and Sequence diagrams.